# can't pass element to waypoint constructor

Tags: javascript, web

I'm trying to get into waypoint.js framework and doing first step of the tutorial.
(the one I'm doing is jquery independent)

This is the error Chrome gives me at load:
[image]

Here's the html:

[image]

Here's the js:

[image]

I don't know if that have anything to do with it but "element" in js code is not highlighted in blue as "handler" is. Also tried firefox, not working either though no errors given at all.

Comment: Make sure you have element with the given id when you are trying to find it using `getElementById`. Either use `DOMContentLoaded` event or put your script at the bottom of document body.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko hey thanks a lot, putting script at the bottom of doc body worked, but why would it, i mean why such thing matters?

Comment: It is the way browser parses document. Roughly speaking, when it comes to script tag it stops parsing and executes script content. Which means the rest of the document were not parsed yet. Thus `getElementById` returns null. So you either have to put your script below the content or use special event that fires when document was parsed.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko thank you so much :)